How to create dynamic path with layout in nuxt2?
i am trying create a nuxt2 project and i wan to do dynamic path with layout  but now is not working
in my nuxt.config.js
import route from './routes.js';
export default {
router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(...route);
    }
  },
}

in my routes.js
import store from './store'
console.log('routes.jshello');
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    meta: { layout: 'GuestLayout', middleware: 'guest' },
    children: [
      { path: '/login', name: 'login', component: './pages/merchant/views/auth/login.vue' },
      { path: '/register', name: 'register', component: './pages/merchant/views/auth/register.vue'},
      { path: '/register_summary/:ref', name: 'register_summary', component: './pages/merchant/views/auth/registerSummary.vue'},
    ]
  }
export default routes;


Hey, you should not use Nuxt2, if possible use Nuxt3. Otherwise, give a read to that page: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes

I guess he doesn't understand where to get the page components from. This should help for the field "component" (in routes.js):
import path from 'path'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    meta: { layout: 'GuestLayout', middleware: 'guest' },
    children: [
      { path: '/login', name: 'login', component: path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/merchant/views/auth/login.vue')},
      { path: '/register', name: 'register', component: path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/merchant/views/auth/register.vue')},
      { path: '/register_summary/:ref', name: 'register_summary', component: path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/merchant/views/auth/registerSummary.vue')},
    ]
  }


